# Handler's post does not get executed while using a `.wait()` -> `.notify()`

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, android-handler

I am trying to spot what I am doing wrong in the piece of code below, but I could not figure it out nor find an answer in other StackOverflow questions.

When running the code below, the code inside the runnable's block does not get executed sometimes, which makes my app hang until an ANR is thrown to the user.

```
private void initializeOnMainThread(final Context appContext) {
    final Object syncLock = new Object();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // some init stuff

            Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 3");
            synchronized (syncLock) {
                Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 4");
                syncLock.notify();
                Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 5");
            }

        }
    };

    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        runnable.run();
    } else {
        uiHandler.post(runnable);
        Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 1");
        try {
            synchronized (syncLock) {
                Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 2");
                syncLock.wait();
                Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG", "STEP 6");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The printed log is as follows:

> D/CUSTOM_TAG: STEP 1
>
> D/CUSTOM_TAG: STEP 2

The `uiHandler` initialization is as follows:

```
val uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

And the `post` is the only method from `uiHandler` that is called in the entire code, no `removeCallbacks`, `removeMessage` or anything alike is ever called.

Why isn`t Android executing the Runnable block?

Comment: is it just for learning purposes? if not, what do you want to achieve actually? cannot you use `HandlerThread` for example?

Comment: What I want to achieve is: while running some background tasks, there are some stuff that needs to be done in the UiThread, and I need to wait for its execution to finish before continuing.

Comment: deadlock it is unlikely but still possible. Keep in mind that if you `notifiy() `before `wait()` the scheduler won't have anything to notifiy to. Where are you creating this thread ?

Comment: @Blackbelt a `notify()` is not happening before `wait()`. As you can see in the question, steps 3 and 4 are never printed in the log (the `notify()` happens after them)

Comment: you mean that you need to wait in the background thread and notify UI one?

Comment: you don't know that for sure. That's up to the scheduler. That can still happen

Comment: @pskink Yes :D. I need to wait in the background thread until the UiThread code I want to execute gets executed.

Comment: @Blackbelt as I said, the logs `STEP 3` and `STEP 4` are never printed out. : /

Comment: so use `HandlerThread` - the docs say: *"Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper. The looper can then be used to create handler classes. Note that start() must still be called."*

Comment: @pskinkm I am using a HandlerThread :D

Comment: i dont see any use of `HandlerThread` in your code

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that this is really an answer, but as long as I cannot figure out what the problem is, I will post a workaround for the problem that I am having.

The workaround consists of trading the `wait()` and `notify()` for the [`CountDownLatch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch) class.

After making that change, the app did not hang anymore (and I may say that using it increased the legibility of the code) - win win.